# Set intent when returning to parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation

An application about which I previously asked requires an ID for a particular activity, which is used to make a database query. When the activity starts I get this ID from an intent, thus:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_counting);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null)
    {
      project_id = extras.getLong("project_id");
    }
    // ... the rest of the initialisation follows here
}
```

This activity (CountingActivity) in turn starts another via the user's interaction (EditProjectActivity) which has the CountingActivity as a parent so that navigation back via the home button works. In AndroidManifest.xml I have this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="myproject.EditProjectActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_project"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:parentActivityName="myproject.CountingActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="CountingActivity" />
    </activity>
```

When a user has finished editing they could do one of three things:

1. Press a 'save' button. The data are saved, finish() is called and the CountingActivity returns.
2. Press the Android back button. The EditProjectActivity is popped off the stack without saving and the Counting Activity returns.
3. Press the application icon in the top left. Somehow, the CountingActivity is started without the project_id intent; this value ends up being set to 0 and nothing can be found in the database, with undesirable results.

Somehow, I need to make sure that the project_id is passed as an intent when navigating back to the parent activity. I tried this without luck:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.home) // I also tried R.id.homeAsUp
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(EditProjectActivity.this, CountingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("project_id",project_id);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But, there's still no project_id and so a database query can't be made. So, if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Try putting project_id in a bundle, then passing the bundle through intent and then receiving the bundle, and getting the prohect _id from that bundle. Worked for me.

Comment: It seems that the answer can in fact be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462456/returning-from-an-activity-using-navigateupfromsametask/16147110#16147110

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY`, the parent activity must be set as `singleTop` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. Otherwise a new instance will be created. See for example [Android: Activities destroyed unexpectedly, null savedInstanceState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212787/android-activities-destroyed-unexpectedly-null-savedinstancestate/)

However, depending on the use case, a simpler alternative may be available. If `EditProjectActivity` is *always* called from `CountingActivity` (and never by itself) and you *always* want to return there, the simplest solution is to just use:

```
if (id == R.id.home)
{
    setResult(...); // optional, whether you want to treat this as save/cancel.
    finish();
}
```